# Framework 7 mainview

Tags: html-framework-7

I am currently using cordova and framework 7 to build a mobile apps
but currently I found out the code in the framework7 document
which is

```
mainView.router.loadPage('gameroom.html');
```

cant work in most typical android phone as well , but it is ok in my Android Emulator

the phone that I cant work in my test is:

```
Oppo R7
Oppo F1s
```

can anybody tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Your html file ('gameroom') is in the same directory as index.html ?

Comment: yes i am sure the html file is same directory as index.html

Comment: any error you see?

Comment: try update webview https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview from your phone